# How to update Vanilla JS variable in scope variable of Angular JS controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var a=1;
function counterincrease(){
    a++;
}  
angular.module('myapp')  
    .controller('MainCtrl',function($scope){  
        $scope.b = a;  
    });
```

I want to keep tracking variable `a` in `$scope.b`

```
<button onclick="counterincrease()">Click me</button>
```

How do I keep tracking it? I tried to put a watch on `a` but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-click`

```
<button ng-click="counterincrease()">Click me</button>
```

Create a `counterincrease` function in a `$scope` and then call the global method from it and update `b` in the `ngClick` handler.

```
angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.b = a;
        $scope.counterincrease = function(){
             counterincrease();
             $scope.b = a;
        };
    });
```

---

There is no need to define the function in Global Scope. I would recommend you to use Angular `service` or `factory`

```
var app = angular.module('myapp');
app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', 'myFactory', function ($scope, myFactory) {
    $scope.b = myFactory.getData();
    $scope.counterincrease = function () {
        myFactory.counterincrease();
        $scope.b = myFactory.getData();
    };
}]);

app.factory('myFactory', function ($http) {
    var a = 0;
    return {
        counterincrease: function () {
            return a++;
        },
        getData: function () {
            return a;
        }
    };
});
```